# Datepicker Popup (ui.bootstrap.datepickerPopup) Format Error

Tags: css, angularjs, uidatepicker

[image]

Following the instructions of: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#getting_started

And using this example in plunker of this page the result is the image below and it must be:
[image]

Where is the problem? in the css....

Comment: Use the element inspector in the Developer Console to see the computed CSS.

Comment: This is my code in the inspector <br> Can you help me?<br><input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-valid-date ng-touched" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" required="required" aria-invalid="false" style="">